# Android SQLite null Select

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Using the following query, I get data from two tables in the db. But if COL5, is empty, do not display even data of(TABLE1). It should also display other data?

```
SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
final List<Dettaglio1> dettagli1 = new ArrayList<Dettaglio1>();     

String sql = "SELECT C._id, " +
            "B.col1, " +
            "B.col2, " +
            "B.col3, " +
            "B.col4, " +
            "B.col5, " +
            "B.col6, " +
            "SUM(C.col01), " +
            "C.col02, " +
            "C.col03 " +
            "FROM table1 B LEFT JOIN table2 C ON (B.col5 = C.col02)";

Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(tabella_conti, null); 
  while (cur.moveToNext()){
      Dettaglio1 d01 = new Dettaglio1();
        d01.id= cur.getString(0);   
        d01.col1= cur.getString(1);                     
        d01.col2= cur.getDouble(2);         
        d01.col3= cur.getString(3);             
        d01.col4 = cur.getString(4);                            
        d01.col5= cur.getString(5);                 
        d01.col6 = cur.getString(6);
        d01.col01 = cur.getDouble(7);                   
        d01.col02 = cur.getString(8);               
        d01.col03= cur.getString(9);                
        dettagli1.add(d01);     

        }
        cur.close();        
        db.close();

....
....
}
```

Comment: In fact, that's what I tried to explain. My objective is to take the data even if `COL5 is empty.` how can I do?

Comment: There is no TABLE1. In theory, a LEFT JOIN should do what you want. Show some example data and the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to include NULL values you should use LEFT or RIGHT join like this:

```
... from table1 as B RIGHT JOIN table2 as C ON (B.col5 = C.col02)
```

If RIGHT join isn't supported on some platforms (thanks to @user3608814, see comments) use LEFT join and change order of tables:

```
... from table2 as C LEFT JOIN table1 as B ON (C.col02 = B.col5)
```

**Update**
If this doesn't help (when as you have written there is no data in `table2` but you still need results) you should **reorganize** your data scheme:
Add explicit foreign key to `table2` that links it to `table1`. Let it be `table2.extID` column. Then it's possible to query like this:

```
... from table1 as B LEFT JOIN table2 as C ON (B._ID = C.extID)
```

Comment: RIGHT JOIN is not supported on Android

Comment: Thanks, never occurred to me. Corrected answer

Comment: no, unfortunately, even so, if there is no data in table2 nothing is displayed. Have you any other ideas?